# For $f(x,y)= y/(x^{2}+1)$, how close to $(0,0)$ should one take $(x,y)$ in order to make $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|<0.001$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> For the function
>   $$f(x,y)= \frac{y}{x^{2}+1}$$
>   how close to the point $(0,0)$ should one take the point $(x,y)$ in order to make $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|<0.001$?

I couldn't find a right approach to this problem. One of my approaches was that after substitution in the absolute value inequality above we get $|y|<0.001 (x^{2}+1)$.

> How to get the solution in terms of distance from $(0,0)$, without using calculus?

Comment: Try to use Taylor series

Comment: I'm looking for approaches without calclus

Comment: The books answer says that $d =\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}<0.001$ I want to  know how is it obtained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way could be as follows:

For convenience let's set $\epsilon = 0.001$.

We wish to find $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| = \left|\frac{y}{1+x^2} \right| \stackrel{!}{<}\epsilon \mbox{ for } \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$$

Now, you may estimate as follows:

$$\left|\frac{y}{1+x^2} \right| = \frac{|y|}{1+x^2} \leq \frac{|y|}{1} = \sqrt{y^2}\leq  \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \stackrel{!}{<} \epsilon$$

From here you see that $\delta = \epsilon=0.001$ does the job.